# UML class diagram for string array

Tags: java, uml, ocl

In UML how should we show a method which return string array in UML method that looks like this

```
public String[] delete(int col, int row){}
```

Is this representation correct?

```
+delete(col: int; row: int): String[]
```

Comment: then i guess it will be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

That is ok, but ideally you should include the bounds in OCL. e.g.

> +delete(col: int, row: int): string[0..*]

This is not an array but a 'bounds' so 
[0..*] is zero to infinite strings.
[0..1] Zero or one strings.
[1..*] 1 to infinite strings.

In this case string is the OCL type not a Java String object, others are Bag, Set etc.

Comment: And for two dimensional array ?

+delete(col: int, row: int): String[0..*][0..*]

is this correct?

Comment: Actually NO, the bounds are an OCL constraint not a *type*, like array. It is actually Object Constraint Language.  I'm not sure of the answer but you should be able to find it at http://search.cpan.org/~kstephens/UMMF-1.02/